# "Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred" for `observe`

Tags: ios, swift, generics, key-value-observing

I have a class that is generic, like:

```
class Row<T> {

    ...

}
```

If I have an instance of `Row` where `T` is `ExampleClass`, I want to be able to do:

```
row.bind(to: \ExampleClass.category)
```

Then in `bind` I want to start observing `ExampleClass.category` for my `ExampleClass` instance that I have in the class.

I've implemented:

```
func bind<Value>(to targetKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Value>) {
    if let model = model as? NSObject {
        model.observe(targetKeyPath, options: [.new ,.old], changeHandler: { _, change in
            Log.info?.msg("Now we have some stuff: \(change)")
        })
    }
}
```

This gives me the error: `Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred`.

How is that possible? The `T` is solved but why can't `Value` be inferred? It should come from the parameter `targetKeyPath`.

Full code for repoducable:

```
class Row<T> {

    let model: T

    init(model: T) {
        self.model = model
    }

    func bind<Value>(to targetKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Value>) {
        if let model = model as? NSObject {
            model.observe(targetKeyPath, options: [], changeHandler: { _, _ in

            })
        }
    }

}
```

How I'd like to use the example class above:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    @objc var age: NSNumber?
}

class Book: NSObject {
    @objc var title: String?
}

let row1 = Row(model: Person())
let row2 = Row(model: Book())

row1.bind(to: \Person.age)
row2.bind(to: \Book.title)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to allow us to reproduce. For example, what's `model`?

Comment: @matt added code to reproduce

Comment: The error you cite appears _without_ reference to whether or not you call `row.bind(to: \ExampleClass.category)`. It's a fact about how `bind` itself is defined. What is there about it that you think resolves `Value`?

Comment: Yes it does. Shouldnt ”Value” be resolved by type of the parameter passed, the same way ”T” is resolved from the parameter passed? :S

Comment: The Value in question is not the Value you've written. You can replace that by V and you'll get the same error. What isn't known here is the `observe` call's Value.

Comment: @matt Yeah, I know that I can replace it by V or X, or w/e. I'll update the example with how I want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably over-thinking this. The problem is that `model` is known only to be an NSObject. You can reproduce simply like this:

```
class ExampleClass:NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var category = ""
}
let model = NSObject()
model.observe(\ExampleClass.category) { _,_ in }
```

Same error. If you change `model` to be an ExampleClass, the problem goes away.

Comment: I know that it isn't what you hoped for. I'm just trying to explain the error message.

Comment: Well, the thing you want to do sounds like the thing I wanted to do and couldn't when I filed this bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5621

Comment: Maybe so, but not much response there I can see.. The conversation rather converged to be about casting from/to generics.

Comment: It's true that I accidentally led the conversation away from the original report, but the original still stands as a reported bug. If you want to pile on with your use case, or submit your own bug report, please do so.